# преобразовать Multipart в JSON (Jackson) для HTTP запроса (Jersey)

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, multipart

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MultiPart multipart = new MultiPart();
multipart.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("metadata", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Metadata(Type, "MyType")), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)); //{\"Type1\" : \"MyType1\",\r\n  \"Type2\" : \"MyType2\"}
multipart.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("content", "/image.png", new MediaType("image", MediaType.MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD)));

String body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(multipart); 
// JsonMappingException: Cannot get entity on a MultiPart instance (through reference chain: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart["entity"])
// Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get entity on a MultiPart instance
```

Как корректно написать что то вроде:

```
String body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(multipart);
```

Требуется тело в таком формате **body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)** для подписи запроса

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: подождите , multipart предназначен для пердачи файлов, из вашего кода следует, что это изображение в формате png. какой результат вы ожидаете получить, когда хотите преобразовать изображение в json (текст)?

Comment: В текущем случае мне необходимо подписать запрос. На Jersey сам multipart нормально уходит с бирером вот так - .post(Entity.entity(multipart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));

Однако для нормальной интеграции необходимо подпись по типу - Signa(TimeStamp, POST, "/resources/", body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

Jackson целиком multipart кушать не хочет. Придумать как сделать body пригодным для перегона в bytes не могу
При этом подпись должна совпасть с отправляемым содержимым (то что в multipart)

Comment: Возможно есть способ отправить в Jersey не multipart а другое тело с тем же форматом? (файл + данные) которое можно будет и в байты переганть.